# Sending Selenium report to e-mail

Tags: java, spring, file-io, jakarta-mail

Im trying to send a Selenium report to my e-mail address.

In my pom I have added spring-context-support and javax.mail-api.

The problem is that I dont know how to read a HTML page into a InputStreamSource, so I can send it to my e-mail address. Can someone please show me? Here is my method for sending e-mail:

```
private void sendMail() {

    MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
    try {
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
        if (emailTo.contains(",")) {
            helper.setTo(emailTo.split(","));
        } else {
            helper.setTo(emailTo);
        }
        helper.setFrom("from@domain.com");
        helper.setSubject("Selenium: Something went wrong");
        helper.setText("Please see the attached report");

        // I need help with this:
        InputStreamSource iss = getInputSteam("Testresult.html");




        helper.addAttachment("Testresult.html", iss,
                "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        mailSender.send(message);
    } catch (javax.mail.MessagingException me) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Messaging exception caught: " + me.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the html page saved somewhere or are you getting it from URL?

Comment: What types are `MimeMessageHelper` and `InputStreamSource`? I don't think they are from javax.mail API. But why don't you use `java.io.InputStream`?

Comment: @Würgspaß Those are Spring Mail constructs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work if the HTML file can be accessed locally (make sure the file path to your file is correct):

```
InputStreamSource iss = FileSystemResource("path/to/your/file");
```

or this, if you can use a URL (in this case via HTTP):

```
InputStreamSource iss = FileSystemResource(new URL("http://my.file.url"));
```

Be aware that `MimeMessageHelper` has a method like this:

```
addAttachment(String attachmentFilename, File file)
```

which would be yet easier if you don't have to care about `contentType`.

Comment: Thank you. The file is located in my resources folder.